# Do ResNets from Microsoft experts represent convolutional neural nets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, residual-networks

I am talking about the article of Kaiming He, Xiangyu Zhang, Shaoqing Ren, Jian Sun (Microsoft Research team):

> ["*Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognitione (2015)*"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf)

**ResNets** won the 1-st place at [Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge 2015 (ILSVRC2015)](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2015/results)

In terms of architecture, do **ResNets** represent convolutional neural networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Residual networks (ResNets) are a type of recurrent neural network (RNN).

[Jürgen Schmidhuber](http://people.idsia.ch/%7Ejuergen/microsoft-wins-imagenet-through-feedforward-LSTM-without-gates.html) :

> Microsoft Research dominated the ImageNet 2015 contest with a deep
> neural network of 150 layers [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdQgU.png). Congrats to Kaiming He & Xiangyu
> Zhang & Shaoqing Ren & Jian Sun on the great results [2]!
>
> **Their CNN layers compute G(F(x)+x), which is essentially a feedforward
> Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) [3] without gates!**
>
> Their net is similar to the very deep Highway Networks [4] (with
> hundreds of layers), which are feedforward LSTMs with forget gates (=
> gated recurrent units) [5].
>
> The authors mention the vanishing gradient problem, but do not mention
> my very first student Sepp Hochreiter (now professor) who identified
> and analyzed this fundamental deep learning problem in 1991, years
> before anybody else did [6].
>
> Apart from the above, I liked the paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdQgU.png) a lot. LSTM concepts keep
> invading CNN territory [e.g., 7a-e], also through GPU-friendly
> multi-dimensional LSTMs [8].
>
> References
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdQgU.png) Kaiming He, Xiangyu Zhang, Shaoqing Ren, Jian Sun. Deep Residual
> Learning for Image Recognition. arxiv:1512.03385
>
> [2] ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge 2015
> (ILSVRC2015): Results
>
> [3] S. Hochreiter, J. Schmidhuber. Long Short-Term Memory. Neural
> Computation, 9(8):1735-1780, 1997. Based on TR FKI-207-95, TUM (1995).
> PDF. Led to a lot of follow-up work, and is now heavily used by
> leading IT companies all over the world.
>
> [4] R. K. Srivastava, K. Greff, J. Schmidhuber. Training Very Deep
> Networks. NIPS 2015; arxiv:1505.00387.
>
> [5] F. A. Gers, J. Schmidhuber, F. Cummins. Learning to Forget:
> Continual Prediction with LSTM. Neural Computation, 12(10):2451-2471,
> 2000. PDF.
>
> [6] S. Hochreiter. Untersuchungen zu dynamischen neuronalen Netzen.
> Diploma thesis, TU Munich, 1991. Advisor: J. Schmidhuber. Overview.
>
> [7a] 2011: First superhuman CNNs  [7b] 2011: First human-competitive
> CNNs for handwriting  [7c] 2012: First CNN to win segmentation contest
> [7d] 2012: First CNN to win contest on object discovery in large
> images  [7e] Deep Learning. Scholarpedia, 10(11):32832, 2015
>
> [8] M. Stollenga, W. Byeon, M. Liwicki, J. Schmidhuber. Parallel
> Multi-Dimensional LSTM, with Application to Fast Biomedical Volumetric
> Image Segmentation. NIPS 2015; arxiv:1506.07452.

http://www.asimovinstitute.org/neural-network-zoo/ :

> Deep residual networks (DRN) are very deep FFNNs with extra
> connections passing input from one layer to a later layer (often 2 to
> 5 layers) as well as the next layer. Instead of trying to find a
> solution for mapping some input to some output across say 5 layers,
> the network is enforced to learn to map some input to some output +
> some input. Basically, it adds an identity to the solution, carrying
> the older input over and serving it freshly to a later layer. It has
> been shown that these networks are very effective at learning patterns
> up to 150 layers deep, much more than the regular 2 to 5 layers one
> could expect to train. **However, it has been proven that these networks
> are in essence just RNNs without the explicit time based construction
> and they’re often compared to LSTMs without gates.**
>
> [image]

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03640.pdf :

> We begin with the observation that **a shallow RNN is exactly equivalent to a very deep ResNet with weight sharing among the layers**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently residual networks share something in common with LSTMs and RNNs, however by definition residual networks are more of a type of convolutional neural network (CNN).

The key difference between a residual network and an unrolled RNN/LSTM is, as mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03640.pdf

> unrolling in (discrete) time the feedback
>   system gives a deep residual network with the **same (that is, shared) weights** among the layers.